# Is it possible to install a 2.5" and 3.5" hard drives in a 5.25" bay in a Mini ITX case?

Tags: hard-drive, installation

I have an SSD and a hard disk drive which I want to mount in a 5.25 optical drive bay in my Mini ITX case. Is this possible and are there any off the shelf solutions for this?

Comment: Some people just use a little double-sided mounting tape to keep the drive in place, but you can get adapter brackets, like http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007VP83BU.  A huge variety available via Google search to match any size drive to any size bay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed adapters made for doing that. The manufacturer of your case might make one.

I can't recommend any one in particular, but you are probably looking for something like this (I guess it has "Sharkoon" stamped on it somewhere):

[image: Original image copyright Sharkoon]

which has no front panel - i.e. it sits completely within the drive bay.

You can also get adapters which allow the drives to be removed from the front, which would look something like (the Icydock logo doesn't seem clear in this picture):

[image: Original image copyright Icydock]

A suitable term to search for is "5.25 to 3.5 and 2.5 adapter".